# Telling angular not to parse certain HTML block

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For the context I'm building syntax highlighting for my angular (1.5.8) application. For syntax highlighting I use `Prism.js` which unfortunately can't highlight my code when I use `ng-include` in my HTML. Quite understandable since it introduces asynchronity. So to overcome the problem I'm creating an angular directive so that I can write something like this:

```
<prism lang="html">
  <md-toolbar layout layout-align="end center"></md-toolbar>
</prism>
```

Then in my directive I'm runnin the contents of the directive through `Prism.highlight(transclusion, Prism.languages[this.lang])` so far so good. It works, but the only problem is, that angular parses my transclusion beforehand and modifies my input html that it adds additional classes because of my used `layout` and `layout-align` directives.

Here lies my question. Can I tell angular that "do not parse this chunk of code"?

Edit: I tried to wrap the input in `<pre></pre>` but that didn't help. Angular still parsed it and added classes.

Edit2: While I'm writing this I have an idea to put html elements outside of angular context giving them unique id. Then writing `<prism code-id="some-unique-id">` then the directive could fetch the dom elem referenced by that uid and include it in the dom. Well, ugly af but could work am I right?

Edit3: I'm extending the post with more code so that you get the whole picture

1: In styleguide.html

```
<!-- MATERIAL DESIGN -->
<div id="material">
  <h1>Material design assets</h1>
  <div ng-include="'./material.html'"></div>
</div>
```

2: In material.html

```
<section>
  <h2>Dialog</h2>
  <md-button class="md-accent">Open sample dialog</md-button>

  <prism lang="html">
    <md-toolbar class="md-primary">
      <header class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <h3 class="md-headline">{{ 'Dialog title' | translate }}</h3>
        <!-- SPACER -->
        <span flex></span>
        <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="ctrl.close()"><i class="material-icons">close</i></md-button>
      </header>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-dialog-content>
      <div class="md-dialog-content">
        <!-- Content here -->
      </div>
    </md-dialog-content>
    <md-dialog-actions layout-padding layout layout-align="end center">
      <!-- stuff here -->
    </md-dialog-actions>
  </prism>
</section>
```

3: In the component

```
class PrismHighlighter {
    static get $descriptor() {
        return {
            controller: PrismHighlighter,
            template: `
                <pre>
                    <code class="language-{{$ctrl.lang}}">
                        <ng-transclude class="transclusion"></ng-transclude>
                    </code>
                </pre>
            `,
            transclude: true,
            bindings: {
                lang: '@'
            }
        }
    }

    static get $inject() {
        return ['$element'];
    }

    constructor($element) {
        this.element = $element;
    }

    $postLink() {
        const codeElem = this.element.find('code');
        const transclusion = $(this.element).find('ng-transclude').html();
        const hCode = Prism.highlight(transclusion, Prism.languages[this.lang]);
        codeElem.html(hCode);
    }
}
module.component('prism', PrismHighlighter.$descriptor);
```

4: And the output

[image]

Now you can clearly see that there are a lot of angular added things there what I don't want :/

Comment: Try putting inside `<code>` tag.

Comment: Did not work sadly :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-non-bindable` directive around it.

For Angular 1.x you can just use:

```
<div ng-non-bindable>
</div>
```

For angular 2.x this check this [post](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/ignoring-angular-2.0-bindings) that shows how to do the same.

Reference:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable